# Getting TypeScript error in undefined(undefined,undefined) with react webpack-sources

Tags: reactjs, webpack

My code is not able to compile with npm run start, getting below error

Failed to compile.

undefined
TypeScript error in undefined(undefined,undefined):
Cannot find type definition file for 'webpack-sources'.
The file is in the program because:
Entry point for implicit type library 'webpack-sources'  TS2688

package.json - https://gist.github.com/divsoft/01aa1739d0830f6275ec78fa137bc9a5

I have used npm install --legacy-peer-deps